# Tiling texture bmp file as texture onto a rectangle in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

I have a pic.bmp that I'm attempting to tile onto a 3 x 2 rectangular flat surface for a demo I'm making.

I'm attempting to keep the aspect ratio of the bmp in tact but I still want to tile it across that surface.  Right now I have the surfaces vertices as (0,0,0), (3,0,0), (0,2,0) and (3,2,0).

How can I apply this bmp to the flat surface and tile it?  What is the best way to do this in GLUT & OpenGL?

Answer (score 3):

See [this NeHe lesson](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06) for a sample. To do tiling just write something like this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        // your surface
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f);  
        glTexCoord2f(3.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 3.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f);  
        glTexCoord2f(3.0f, 2.0f); glVertex3f( 3.0f,  2.0f,  0.0f);  
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f,  2.0f,  0.0f);  
glEnd();
```

This will set texture coordinates to tile any texture 3x2 times on this surface.