# How do I fill the screen with a rectangle in OpenGL ortho mode?

Tags: c, opengl, fullscreen, textures, aspect-ratio

I have a single 640x480 texture that needs to fill the screen. So far, I can make it work with a square texture, but not a rectangular one.

```
glViewport(0, 0, display->w, display->h);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

double aspectRatio = (double)display->w / (double)display->h;

if (display->w <= display->h)
    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1 / aspectRatio, 1 / aspectRatio, -1, 1);
else
    glOrtho(-1 * aspectRatio, 1 * aspectRatio, -1, 1, -1, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

What modifications do I need to make so that it will fit any texture to the screen, regardless of its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

This may have some relevance.

[Tiling texture bmp file as texture onto a rectangle in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743097/tiling-texture-bmp-file-as-texture-onto-a-rectangle-in-opengl)

You may wish to consider ARB extension texture rectangle as an alternative approach to (assuming glTexImage2D?) http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html

Comment: If I understand everything correctly (and I likely don't, since this is my first time with OpenGL), I only need the texture rectangle extension if my card doesn't support non-power-of-two textures. I'm already able to create the texture and display it on the screen, but my ortho setup is making the quad square. I think my calculations just need to be tweaked, but I'm not sure exactly what needs to be done.